# How do I load data from a text file in python?

Tags: python

I'm basically writing text to a file for example

```
    data = ("save.data", "a+")
    data.write(u"name = 'zrman'")
```

I wan't to be able to load that file and allow me to do this in python

```
    print name
```

Any help would be great

-Thx

Comment: It's not *exactly* what you want, but look at [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

Comment: Pickle wont work because I want to allow the program to make its own variables

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `pickle` would work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#examples) Python module. It's exactely what you're looking for.

### Write :

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.set('main', 'name', 'zrman')
with open('conf.ini', 'wb') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

### Read :

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('conf.ini')

print config.sections()
# ['main']

print config.items('main')
# [('name', 'zrman')]
```

Comment: Thanks ill look into this its alot more complicated then exec() but it might work beter in the long run

Comment: **never** use exec(), especially in your case, I can't figure out a worse idea. You'll have tons of problems, and worst : *unseen* problems (like in php ;))

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), this will walk you through the process of reading and writing files in python.

Comment: This wont rly work ither ive already looked at it and there not much help there and json cant be used because to my knowledge it cant load variables like i want it to

Comment: That is incorrect. JSON is intended precisely for this use. If you think your problem is unique, I suggest reading up on JSON (and other similar tools).

Answer (score -2):

You could read in the lines and then `exec` the code:

```
f = open('workfile', 'w')
for line in f:
    exec(line)

print name
```

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend opening a text file and just running `exec()` on everything in it.

Comment: This is a case where `exec()` is *really* dangerous.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 ...uh, isn't "opening up a text file and running `exec` on it" basically what `import` does? I mean, I wouldn't use `exec` here, because overkill/namespace pollution, but have no qualms about writing a `settings.py` and importing that everywhere, which is basically running an under-the-covers `exec` on a config file, just with optimizations.

Comment: whats srong with exec()

Comment: @NightShadeQueen - If I'm going to be running something as executable code, I want it to be labeled as such. I only download/install/import programs where I trust the source, but a text file is harmless... unless it contains malicious code and we run `exec()` on it instead of parsing it in a safer manner.

Comment: @Zrman2012 On top of potential security issues: `exec` makes mockery of namespaces, is slow (because, seriously, if you don't need python's lexer in this situation and with exec, you don't even get the benefits of .pyc files), and [your tracebacks can become pretty useless](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/445238-getting-better-traceback-info-exec-execfile-introspection). It's a bit of a maintenance horror, really.